# Issue with Processing unbinary function

Tags: bit-manipulation, processing

I am using **Processing 2.2.1**. When I try to use `unbinary()` on a 32-bit integer, every bit can be flipped except the first.

For example,

```java
int output = unbinary("10000000000000000000000000000000");
```

this will throw:

```java
"NumberFormatException: For input string: "10000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Does `unbinary()` not handle 32-bit integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Processing's source](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java), the `unbinary()` function calls `Integer.parseInt()` under the hood. According to [the Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-), the `Integer.parseInt()` function expects a signed value. This is causing a problem, because 32-bit ints don't have a sign, they have a **sign bit**.

In other words, the `unbinary()` function isn't treating your input 32-bit value the same way Java (and therefore Processing) would treat a 32-bit int.

The maximum number an `int` can hold is `2,147,483,647`. Your input binary value converts to `2,147,483,648`, which is over the limit.

**But the value is a binary number with 32 digits! Isn't that a 32-bit integer?**

The `unbinary()` function is treating the binary values as "human readable", which means that it expects a sign for negative numbers. So it accepts things like `-101` to represent `-5` in binary. But under the hood, that's not how negative binary values are treated. Java uses [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) to represent negative numbers, which means that `-5` is represented by `11111111111111111111111111111011` in binary.

It gets a little complicated, but basically: if a binary number starts with a `1`, that means it's a negative number.

So, your input value of `10000000000000000000000000000000` evaluates to the lowest possible `int` value of `-2,147,483,648` but **only in machine-readable format.** The `unbinary()` function is treating it as the "human readable" format, which is why you're getting the discrepancy.

**How do I fix this problem?**

It really depends on why you need to go from binary to integer. But you might use the `Integer.parseUnsignedInt()` function instead, which takes binary values in "machine-readable" format:

```java
int output = Integer.parseUnsignedInt("10000000000000000000000000000000", 2);
```

Comment: way faster than I was and very detailed as well: nice one! (+1)

Comment: Thanks @George! This one had me scratching my head at first. I always have trouble keeping binary stuff in my brain!